# Covariant differentiation in polar coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to strengthen my intuition about covariant derivatives by solving some examples. The example I chose is very trivial but I'm still getting things wrong.

I considered a vector field in polar coordinates:
$$\vec{W}(r,\theta) = r\vec{e_r} + \theta \vec{e_\theta}$$

which basically takes the vector pointing towards the point and attaches it to it. I also considered a simple path: $$\gamma(t) = t\vec{e_r} + c\vec{e_\theta}$$

which is a line passing through the origin making a constant angle. Intuitively, I know that $\frac{d\vec{W}}{dt} = \vec{e_r}$ because the vector field grows in this direction along this path. However, my calculation shows something different:

$$\frac{d\vec{W}}{dt} = \frac{dr}{dt}\frac{\partial \vec{W}}{\partial r} + \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{\partial \vec{W}}{\partial \theta} = \frac{dr}{dt}\frac{\partial \vec{W}}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial \vec{W}}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\vec{e_r} + \theta \vec{e_\theta}) = \vec{e_r} + \theta\frac{\partial \vec{e_\theta}}{\partial r} = \vec{e_r} + \frac{c}{r} \vec{e_\theta} = \vec{e_r} + \frac{c}{t} \vec{e_\theta}$$

Now the first term I got correctly. However, why is there a dependence on $\vec{e_\theta}$? I'm sure this result is wrong but I can't find the wrong step. Thank you very much.

Comment: When the angle along the path is constant over it parameter $t$, why do you think it it changes with radial length? $$\dfrac{\partial c\mathrm e_\theta}{\partial r} = 0$$

Comment: I wasn't differentiating the parameter. I was differentiating the basis vector which changes with respect to r.

Comment: Precisely.  When the angle is constant over the path, its derivative with respect to $r$ is zero  ($\vec 0$).

Comment: But $\vec{e_\theta}$ varies with respect to $r$.

Comment: No, $\vec{\mathrm e_\theta}$ varies only with the angle.  $$\vec{\mathsf e_r}=\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle\\\vec{\mathsf e_\theta}=\langle -\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle$$

Comment: Oh okay I see. I think I used 2 different conventions at the same time. The convention I used was $\vec{e_\theta} = -r\sin(\theta)\vec{e_x} + r\cos(\theta)\vec{e_y}$

Comment: Note that this coordinate frame is not defined at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the commentator Graham Kemp, I found the solution. The problem was that I used two different conventions. There is a convention that $\vec{e_\theta}$ scales with r, and a convention that keeps it constant with respect to $r$.

Since I am following the convention that $\vec{e_\theta} = -r\sin\theta \vec{e_x} + r\cos\theta \vec{e_y}$, the vector field I should be using is: $\vec{W}(r,\theta) = r \vec{e_r} + \frac{\theta}{r}\vec{e_\theta}$ so there won't be a change in the angle.

This makes the cancellation happens as:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\frac{\theta}{r}\vec{e_\theta}) = -\frac{\theta}{r^2}\vec{e_\theta} + \frac{\theta}{r^2}\vec{e_\theta} = 0$$